# Generating 3SAT circuit for Integer factorization example

Tags: np, sat, factorization

I read somewhere that 3SAT can be used to solve Integer Factorization.

If that is true, could someone teach me a simple example of generating the 3SAT by using a small number? Let's say you are given the number 6, then the factors are 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6755/fast-reduction-from-rsa-to-sat answers this question directly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a research level question, but it follows immediately from the NP-hardness of 3SAT.  The old book "Computers and Intractability" by Garey and Johnson used to be (i.e. there might be something better now) a good place to learn this topic.  It's not something that can be explained in a few paragraphs.  cs.stackexchange.com (the computer science stackexchange) is a better place for this type of question if you need further help.